# How can I skip first line reading from stdin?

Tags: python, stdin

```
 while 1:
     try:
         #read from stdin
         line = sys.stdin.readline()
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         break
     if not line:
         break
     fields = line.split('#')
     ...
```

How can I skip first line reading from `stdin`?

Answer (score 9):

```
infile = sys.stdin
next(infile) # skip first line of input file
for line in infile:
     if not line:
         break
     fields = line.split('#')
     ...
```

Comment: This is way better than my example :)  Out of curiosity: Why not directly do `next(sys.stdin)`? Why alias it?

Comment: @exhuma, I think it's a little more readable. Others may like to use `sys.stdin` everywhere. Just personal taste (until you need to refactor the code to be able to optionally read from somewhere else)

Comment: If you want to foresee refactoring I would put it into a function taking the file as argument ;) -- But I see your point :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `enumerate` function in order to to that:

```
for place, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if place: # when place == 0 the if condition is not satisfied (skip first line) 
        ....
```

The documentation of [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: I find it wasteful to use `enumerate` for this (just a gut-feeling). It does not *look* right. There are cleaner solutions. I find @gnibbler's so far the most pythonic solution.